# Simplifying three variables boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

$$F(A,B,C)= (AC+ABC')(BC+B'C')= A(C+BC')(BC+B'C')$$
What is the next step? Please help me I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can go on expanding, giving 
$$ (C + BC')(BC + B'C') = BCC + BCC' + BBC'C + BB'CC' $$
Now $BB' = CC' = \bot$ and $CC = C$, hence we get 
$$ (C + BC')(BC + B'C') = BC $$
Therefore $F(A,B,C) = ABC$.